# Find the equation of a straight line

Tags: geometry

Find the equation of a straight line with gradient $-2$ that passes through the midpoint of $(5,-2)$ and $(-3,4)$.

I do not now where to start with this question. I just need to understand the concept of this. No straight answer please. I need an explanation. This would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suppose gradient is the slope of the line, am I right? Can you compute the coordinates of the mid point?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

equation of line $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$

now you have m(gradient) and a point ($x_1,y_1$) which is mid point of two given points.just find out mid point of given point.

for mid point:  If C(x,y) is mid point of $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$

then $x=\dfrac {x_1+x_2}{2}$ and $y=\dfrac {y_1+y_2}{2}$

Comment: Which given point: (5, -2) or (-3, 4)

Comment: yes! $(x_1,y_1)=(1,1)$

Comment: What do you mean yes!? =)

Comment: Is that the answer?

Comment: None of the given points, @MarkZakhem , but their middle point...

Comment: @MarkZakhem  middle point+ slope are the data you need in this exercise to find the line...please check my answer for additional background.

Answer (score 2):

- A brief introduction

A line in $\mathbb R^2$ is described by an equation of the form

$$y=mx+q~~~ (*)$$

(in cartesian coordinates), where the parameters $m$ and $q$ are called the slope (you called it gradient) and the intercept.

Why is the slope called...slope? For any two distinct points $P=(x_0,y_0)$ and $Q=(x_1,y_1)$ on the line $(*)$ the ratio

$$\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0} $$

is constant, and it is equal to $m$! If you draw $P$ and $Q$ in  $\mathbb R^2$ you surely can understand why such ratio, i.e. $m$, is then called the slope.

The other parameter, called the intercept, measures the distance between the point of intersection between the line and the y-axis and the point $(0,0)$.

In summary, to find a line in $\mathbb R^2$ you need to find these 2 parameters. To do so, you could specify that the line passes through 2 distinct points or, (this is your case!) you can specify the slope of the line you are searching for *and* 1 point lying on it.

Concretely, to solve your exercise you need to find such point, as the slope is given as datum. The exercise says that the point lying on the line is the mid-point of the segment in $\mathbb R^2$ with endpoints given by $(5,-2)$ and $(-3,4)$.

All you need is to find such mid-point and arrive at $q$ by putting the coordinates of the mid-point in (*), with $m=-2$.

- **Explicit solution (Spoilers)**

The mid point of the segment with endpoints $(5,-2)$ and $(-3,4)$ is

$$M:=\left(\frac{5-3}{2},\frac{-2+4}{2}\right)=(1,1).$$

Using the datum $m=-2$, we search for the line $y=mx+q$ in $\mathbb R^2$ passing through $M$. Using $M$'s coordinates we arrive at

$$1=-2\cdot 1+q \Leftrightarrow 1+2=q\Leftrightarrow 3=q, $$

and the line is $y=-2x+3$.

Comment: There is no need the give the answer, but your work is pretty good.

Comment: Good point: I edit the answer, adding an introduction. Thanks!

Comment: x is x1 right??

Comment: I'm not sure how you got 1=-2 . 1 +q

Comment: Then how you got q=3

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: You would like to find a line with $m=-2$, and passes through a point (the mid-point) $(x,y) = (1,1)$. Substitute all these into the straight line form $y = mx + q$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Find the point from where the given line passes and use the slope point form to find the required equation of straight line.

**Solution:-**

We have,

> - Gradient of line $(m) = -2$
> - The line passes through the mid-point of the line joining $(5,-2), (-3,4)$

The mid-point is given by,

$\longrightarrow (x_1, y_1) = \left(\dfrac{5-3}{2}, \dfrac{-2+4}{2}\right)$

$\longrightarrow (x_1, y_1) = (1,1) $

Now, using point slope form of straight line:-

$\longrightarrow y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$

$\longrightarrow y-1 = (-2)(x - 1)$

$\longrightarrow y-1 = -2x +2$

$ \longrightarrow y+2x =3$

This is the required equation of straight line.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the $\mathrm{grad}(m)$ is $-2$. So the midpoint of those two points will be given as :

$$ x_0 = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$$

$$y_0 = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}$$

Therefore,

$$(x_0,y_0) = (\frac{5-3}{2}, \frac{4-2}{2})$$

$$(x_0,y_0) = (1,1)$$

Now we know both the gradient and a point so by the formula:

$$(y-y_0) = m(x-x_0)$$

$$(y-1) = -2(x-1)$$

$$y-1 = 2-2x$$

$$2x + y = 3$$

Hope that helps!